# Is this a heap pollution work around?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions, heap-pollution

I have a constructor like below

```
public MyConstructor(MyObject<T> ... objects) {
     // ...
}
```

Eclipse warns me with the following message:

> Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter objects

I change the constructor like this:

```
public MyConstructor(MyObject<T>[] objects) {
     // ...
}
```

Now, the warning disappears. However, I think the potential danger is not solved.

Is this workaround valid ?

Comment: `MyObject<T> ... objects` and `MyObject<T>[] objects` behave similar but they're not the same...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a way it is a workaround. Creating arrays of non-reifiable component type is unsafe. Therefore such array creation expressions are disallowed by the compiler:

```
// List<String> is erased to List => disallowed
Object example = new List<String>[] { null, null };

// List<?> is effectively reifiable => allowed
Object example = new List<?>[] { null, null };
```

Yet, hidden array creations via variable arity methods, such as `Arrays.asList`, are allowed.

```
// RHS amounts to Arrays.asList(new List<String>[] { null, null })
List<List<String>> example = Arrays.asList(null, null);
```

Since you disallowed this array creation, your heap can no longer be polluted. But: How are you ever going to call that constructor?

Please note that your constructor may not pollute the heap at all. The only way it does is if

- it converts the array to a less specifc type (i.e. `MyObject<?>[]` or `Object[]`) or
- it lets the array escape somehow (i.e. assigning it to a field and returning from a getter or passing it to a potentially unsafe method).

If you do neither you can mark the constructor as having `@SafeVarargs` and the warning goes away.

Answer (score 2):

> However, because of type erasure, the compiler converts the varargs
>   formal parameter to `Object[]` elements. Consequently, there is a
>   *possibility* of heap pollution.

As we know the reason of this warning mainly based on type erasure now it's clearly stated in Java Docs for [Heap Pollution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution) that,

> **If you ensure that your code compiles without warnings, then no heap pollution can occur.**

And More on this

> The compiler has already generated a warning when it translated the
>   varargs formal parameter `List<String>... l` to the formal parameter
>   `List[] l`. **This statement is valid**; the variable l has the type `List[]`,
>   which is a *subtype of* `Object[]`.

So that

> Consequently, the compiler does not issue a warning or error if you
>   assign a List object of any type to any array component of the
>   objectArray array.

<sub>All quoted statements are copied from Java Doc</sub>